# IIS Manager Went Missing and HTTP Error 503

Tags: windows, http, iis

I am running Windows 10 Pro (10.0.16299). IIS Manager missing and web app returns HTTP error 503

I am IIS Manager 7 as a web server for my web app. The default MSFT web site comes up but my web app returns error 403. Tried to find iis manager, but it is nowhere to be seen. I see it in control panel but double-clicking does not start anything. 
This was working last Friday and it is not on following Tuesday. Our IT installs patches using some other way, I am not able to Windows Update.
In Windows Features, teh checkboxes are checked, seems to imply it is installed. Tried to uncheck those to remove and add them back, but the removal returned error 0x80073712. Running .NET Framework 4.7.
Any thoughts would be helpful. If I can start it up, maybe fix it.

Comment: Use a debugger to launch inetmgr.exe from IIS installation folder, and you might learn why it crashes.

Comment: Since I tried to remove and re-add, it is gone. And now trying to add it back in Windows Features returns error 0x80073712.